# How to pass extra data from this activity to the next activity?

Tags: android

how to pass extra data from this activity?

```
public class DetailActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }

    @SuppressLint("NextAPI")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        Button btnForum = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnForum);
        Button btnKuis = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnKuis);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        showInfo();

        final Button btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent newActivity = new Intent(DetailActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(newActivity);
            }
        });

        btnForum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent forum = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, Forum.class);                    ;
                startActivity(forum);   
            }

        });

        btnKuis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent kuis = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, Kuisioner.class);                 ;
            startActivity(kuis);    
            }
        });
    }

    public void showInfo(){
        final TextView tNrp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtNrp);
        final TextView tName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        final TextView tSmt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSmt);
        final TextView tStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);

        String url = "http://xxx/blabla/getID.php";

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String MhsID = intent.getStringExtra("idm");

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sMhsID", MhsID));

        String resultServer  = getHttpPost(url,params);

        String strMemberID = "";
        String strNrp = "";
        String strPassword = "";
        String strName = "";
        String strSmt = "";
        String strStatus = "";

        JSONObject c;
        try {
            c = new JSONObject(resultServer);

            strNrp = c.getString("idm");
            strName = c.getString("nama-mahasiswa");
            strSmt = c.getString("semester");
            strStatus = c.getString("status-mahasiswa");

            if(!strMemberID.equals(""))
            {
                tNrp.setText(strNrp);
                tName.setText(strName);
                tSmt.setText(strSmt);
                tStatus.setText(strStatus);
            }
            else
            {
                tNrp.setText("-");
                tName.setText("-");
                tSmt.setText("-");
                tStatus.setText("-");       
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getHttpPost(String url,List<NameValuePair> params) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) { // Status OK
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Log", "Failed to download result..");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
        }
    }
```

this **DetailActivity** already have extra data from the previous activity, but i need to pass extra data "idm" to **Kuisioner** Activity. can anyone teach me how to do that? please this is really important to me :(

Comment: Ohh.. Still not able to solve this?

Comment: yes im stuck, i dont understand whatve u tell me before. im so noob :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `String MhsID` as class level member field like,

```
public class DetailActivity extends Activity {

 private String MhsID = null;
```

Now in showInfo get Intent data like,

```
public void showInfo(){
        ....
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        MhsID = intent.getStringExtra("idm");
        ....
```

And pass values of `MhsID` to `Kuisioner` Activity using `putExtra()` via `Intent` as you did in previous activity

```
btnKuis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent kuis = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, Kuisioner.class);   
            kuis.putExtra("idm",MhsID);              
            startActivity(kuis);    
            }
        });
```

And get `String idm` in `Kuisioner` Activity same as this activity.

Comment: sir, `putStringExtra` is undefined for the type intent. so, i need to use this `private String MhsID = null;` too at Kuisioner activity?

Comment: i think i need to recheck my whole activities again  coz I have tried all the solutions from everyone. but its still doesnt fix maybe i missed something. thank sir, please don't get tired of answering my question :D

Answer (score 0):

in DetailActivity.java:

```
Intent kuis = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, Kuisioner.class);                 
kuis.putExta("Key_hossam", "value"); // just add this line
startActivity(kuis);
```

in Kuisioner.java:

inside the onCreate method just write these lines

```
 Intent intent= getIntent();
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
     if(b!=null)
     {
            String value =(String) b.get("Key_hossam");
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is all explained [HERE](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Just add this line of code:

```
intent.putExtra(name, value);
```

So starting new **Kuisioner** activity should look like this:

```
String value = "Example value"
Intent kuis = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, Kuisioner.class);
kuis.putExtra("idm", value);
startActivity(kuis);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with too many variables, and want to pass data among activities, I suggest make your Activity-variables *static* , and use with class name, no more maintaining variables.

Note : I assume you are using Fragments, you may come back to activities again n again.

Comment: downvoters @ why don't u give a solution, if not , don't down tricks